# why bash history overlap the prompt when scroll up in the history?

Tags: bash, rhel, command-history, bashrc

I customized my bash prompt, PS1 value.

`~/.bashrc`:

```
Color_Off='\e[0m'       # Text Reset
BGreen='\e[1;32m'       # Green
BPurple='\e[1;35m'      # Purple
BWhite='\e[1;37m'       # White
BIBlue='\e[1;94m'       # Blue
PS1="[\[$BGreen\w\]\[$Color_Off\]]\n[\[$BPurple\u\]\[$BWhite\]@\[$BIBlue\h\]\[$Color_Off\]]\$ "
```

When I scroll up in the history with up arrow from the keyboard, after a lot of command I can see these:

```
[/etc]
[bicocca@bicoccag]$ vi
[/etc]
[bicocca@bicoccag]$ vim
[/etc]
[bicoclear
```

The command overlaps the prompt. How I can resolve the issue? I tried to search in Google but I did not found anything.

I am using RHEL6.4.

Comment: As a side note, I would suggest having the Prompt Escape Sequences (`\w`,`\n`,`\u`, etc) to the right of the closing `\]` for the color sequence. More over, if you are going to use vars for your colors, add the brackets to the var (`BGreen='\[\e[1;32m\]'), much cleaner.